# How to exclude files from a pull request?

Tags: git, pull-request

I will like to perform a pull and merge request but also I would like to exclude some files from this pull request.

```
Example: a.py  b.py c.py
```

I would like to peform a pull request and merge except `b.py` file.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

[edit] the file is not committed it yet.

Comment: is it already committed in your repo?

Answer (score 4):

Make two branches from where you are right now, for example `my-pull-request` and `other-change`.

Commit a.py and c.py to `my-pull-request`, and b.py to `other-change`. Push the `my-pull-request` branch to Github, and create the pull request.

Answer (score 4):

Commit `a.py` and `c.py`, `git stash` the rest, perform the request, then `git stash pop` to restore your `b.py`

Comment: This is insufficient if you have already committed the unwanted file to the branch that you want to merge

Comment: @Domi OP stated that the file is not committed yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try pulling all the files and reverse the files to a specific commit. Then push your changes if you want. You can also stack your changes, pull and then apply your stack